# Can I turn off autocomplete for a Pikaday component?

Tags: javascript, pikaday

I have a Pikaday date-picker component and it has a list of suggested (previous) values covering the calendar when using Chrome.  I've tried autocomplete='off' and autocomplete='new-password' and neither of them seem to fix the issue.

along these lines

```
<input type="text" class="js-date-picker" id="xyz" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

So looking at the comments so far either I have completely misunderstood the page that i was looking at (referenced by Liam in the comments) or I've not explained the issue properly.

So On Chrome autocomplete="off" is bypassed.  I am getting something like this...

[image]

I wondered if the hint, which the referenced page implies would work for any input field, but which, generally all examples use for input of type password (for obvious reasons) autocomplete="new-password" might help.  It hasn't helped, and for Chrome (specifically) out of Chrome, Chromium, Firefox & Safari I am still getting the unwanted behaviour.

Does anyone have any hints for what I should try next ?

Comment: basically, it work as a pair with other field, suppose you have two field username and password then you have to write autocomplete="username" for username input and  autocomplete="new-password" for password input.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type to date made it work.  Obviously it added more work hiding the default calendar popup but that wasn't too tricky...

```
<input type="date" class="js-date-picker" id="xyz" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the suggestions just by adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute.

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="datepicker" name="start_date">
```